# node pools vs number of nodes in one pool

Tags: kubernetes, digital-ocean

When provisioning a k8 cluster, in the digital ocean's dashboard, under choose cluster capacity, i see an option to either add nodes in a pool or add a new pool altogether. I don't quite understand the difference.

DO gives the following suggestion which is quite ambiguous to me -

> Increasing the number of nodes in a pool lets you run more instances
>   of the scheduled services. Adding more node pools allows you to
>   schedule pods to different node pools so each pod has the RAM, CPU,
>   and storage it requires. You can add and remove nodes and node pools
>   at any time.

Can anyone give me an example when one increases nodes in a pool and when one creates a different pools altogether?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets suppose I am running my website server using Kubernetes. Initially, I just put my website up and have given two nodes in my node-pool-a, so anyone who visits my website will be directed to one of the two nodes in the node-pool-a. After a few weeks my visitors increase so I add another node into the node-pool which now has 3 nodes to serve my visitors.

Now, I decide to add a new feature to my website. This is isolated from the older node-pool (is a micro-service) so this would require a new node-pool-b with x nodes. And then any visitor who uses that feature will be directed to node-pool-b

Basically, it's the same logic has vertical and horizontal scaling.

Vertical scaling = increase memory/CPU on current machine = increase nodes in existing node pool
Horizontal scaling = adding more machines = adding a new node-pool to serve a different purpose.

Comment: When you add new feature as a micro-service, how would you ensure it gets isolated from other pool? It can get scheduled in node-pool-a, right?

Comment: Also to add to the above query, master is one per cluster or per node-pool?

Comment: There is one master node per project. Basically, from your perspective, you'll only ever have to deal with one master node. If you're using cloud services (e.g. GCP) they handle the master node for you.

In your deployment config, you have the ability to specifiy what nodes/node-pools that process will be routed to. So for node-pool-a I would write:
```
nodeSelector:
        Focus: node-pool-a
```
I called it Focus, you can have any key/value pair you want.

Comment: Node Pools are not meant for isolation of applications from each other. Kubernetes clusters and node pools are actually good tools for sharing resources between applications as their resource usage fluctuates (one application has less of a usage now, so others get to use more for cheap). I also don't think the analogy to vertical or horizontal scaling applies. Increasing nodes in node pool IS horizontal scaling, it's not analogous to vertical scaling because you can't run a 16G app on two nodes in a single pool of 8G nodes.

Answer (score 6):

From GCP's documentation:

> A node pool is a group of nodes within a cluster that all have the same configuration.

Node Pools have a specific node type, which tells them what type of virtual machines they can use as their nodes. For example, I can have these three node pools:

highmem: 4 vCPUs, 32G of RAM and no GPU

highcpu: 8 vCPUs, 16G of RAM and no GPU

gpu: 4 vCPUs, 8G of RAM, 1 Nvidia Tesla GPU

I can scale up each of these node pools independently, I can have 3 highmem nodes in my pool for processes that use a lot of memory, but less CPU, while I have only 1 node in my highcpu pool for processes that use a lot of CPU, but less RAM. Meanwhile I have a node pool for GPU processes such as Tensorflow or Image processing programs. [Assigning pods to node pools](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/) is done through node selector or affinity options in resource definitions.

So, having different node pools gives you the ability to use fine-tuned VMs for differnet purposes. If you were limited to a single pool, you would have to use large VMs with a lot of RAM, CPU and GPU, and that would be extremely expensive and inefficient.

Please note that node pools are not meant to allow "isolation" of applications. In order to logically separate applications, namespaces can be used rather than node pools. Node pools are only meant to be used for managing resources and virtual machine types used.